# Filter record on the basis of textbox in datagrid using stored procedure in c#

Tags: c#, search, stored-procedures

I want to filter rows on a datagrid on the basis of the textbox and I am using a stored procedure what should I do for that my code is following:

I wrote the query in stored procedure for selection is:

```
if @operation =1
select * from Item_Configuration where itemId like '%' + itemId + '%'
```

and C# code is

```
private void btnSrch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection();

    try
    {
        SqlCommand selectItem = new SqlCommand("Item_Configuration_SP", conn1);
        selectItem.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


      if (itemId.Text=="")
            {
                selectItem.Parameters.Add("@operation", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                selectItem.Parameters["@operation"].Value = 1;

                selectItem.Parameters.Add("@itemId", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                selectItem.Parameters["@itemId"].Value = itmId.Text;

            SqlDataReader myReader = selectItem.ExecuteReader();
            List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                if (myReader.HasRows)
                {
                    Item item = new Item();
                    item = MapItem(myReader, item);
                    list.Add(item);
                }
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
        }
    }
}
```

now i get all record on the grid the record is not filtering on the basis of textbox i cant find where i am wrong please help

Comment: it's **stored** procedure - as in **STORED** inside your database - those have nothing to do with a *store* .....

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using Sql Server your query is worng

Instead of this

```
select * from Item_Configuration where itemId = '%' + itemId + '%'
```

It must be

```
select * from Item_Configuration where itemId LIKE '%' + itemId + '%'
```

Comment: yes have done with this like statement later but it does not working

Answer (score 0):

Also you'll have to add this if you are getting operation id from textbox's input

```
selectItem.Parameters["@operation"].Value = txtbox.Text.Trim();
```

Comment: if itemID is name of your text box then your code and condition is incorrect.. you have used if (itemId.Text=="") i guess set a breakpoint and then check your code flow...